# Installing and Using GitLab with remote email server

Tags: gitlab

I want to install GitLab on my personal computer which is on a residential internet network, this means that I cannot run my own email server but I have a hosting plan that comes with its own smtp server that I can remotely connect to. Is it possible to install Gitlab and have it use the remote SMTP server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use external mail server. here is [extract from this page](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html):

> If you would rather send application email via an SMTP server instead
>   of via Sendmail, add the following configuration information to
>   `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.
>
> Warning: Your `smtp_password` should not contain any String delimiters used in Ruby or YAML (f.e. ') to avoid unexpected behavior
>   during the processing of config settings.
>
> There are example configurations at the end of this page.

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.server"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "smtp user"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "smtp password"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "example.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'

# If your SMTP server does not like the default 'From: gitlab@localhost' you
# can change the 'From' with this setting.
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@example.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'noreply@example.com'
```